# How can I avoid losing my class name when I bundle source with webpack in production mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

When I bundle code below in development mode and run abc(),

```
class Foo { ... }

export function abc () { return new Foo(); }
```

I got `Foo { ... }`.

But bundle with production mode, I got something like `k { ... }` and I lost information about class name.

How can I avoid this?

In other words, I want to minify code except class name because I want to use source as a library with `npm install my-github-repository` and `require("abc")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webpack configure sourcemap and then use the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin package to set the output souremap to keep the class name and function name

```js
new UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    parallel: 4,
    uglifyOptions: {
        keep_classnames: true,
        keep_fnames: true
    }
})
```